# How to find matching strings for lists inside lists?

Tags: python

So I have a list

```
myList = [["hello my name is john"],["hey my name is john"],["hello my name is smith"]]
```

And I want the user to be able to search `hello` and the output to be

```
"hello my name is john" 
"hello my name is smith"
```

Or search `john` and the output to be

```
"hello my name is john"
"hey my name is john"
```

The code I have at the moment does not have any output

```
def pattern():
    search = input("Search: ")
    match = [word for word in myList if search in word]
    for confirmedMatch in match:
        print(confirmedMatch)

pattern()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your list.

You code works if your list is a list of strings rather than a list of lists.

`myList = ["hello my name is john","hey my name is john","hello my name is smith"]`

Given your initial solution, it checks if "hello" is an element in the list. You want it to check if it is a substring of the string.

If you would rather it work with a list of lists, the line

`match = [word for word in myList if search in word]` becomes

`match = [word for word in myList if search in word[0]]` (assuming the inner lists have only one element)

Comment: Yeah I realise that making it a list of lists is a more difficult way of doing so but it is what I am required to do, thank you for the help though +1

Comment: @LiamEmery The solution here is correct; look at the last code section. If that works, I would suggest marking this up as the answer.

Comment: If the inner lists have multiple elements, `if search in word[0]` could be replaced by either  `if any(search in e for e in word)` or `if all(search in e for e in word)` depending on what you want to achieve.